# Python Neural Network : TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

Tags: python, neural-network, spyder

I want to use python to training my neural network case, and i try to fix some problem, but I recognize a problem.

The console code is look like that:

[image]

The original code like that:

```
@staticmethod
def colSpec(nparray: 'np.ndarray', rangeStr:str=None,batchStart:str=None, batchEnd:str=None)->'np.ndarray':
    '''
        Specify certain column data by selecting some columns or batched rows of data.   --- UPDATED (Dexter) 20181210

        Parameters
        ------------------------------

        nparray     `np.ndarray<np.array<(int|float|str)>>`   - Data table to be selected.

        rangeStr    `str`   - Index range string for selecting certain columns for the transformation.

        batchStart  `int`   - The starting index (inclusive) of the data rows.

        batchEnd    `int`   - The ending index (exclusive) of the data rows.

        Returns
        ------------------------------

        `np.ndarray<np.array<(int|float|str)>>`   - Data table with requested selection range.
    '''
    # Convert to np array if it's not.
    if not isinstance(nparray, np.ndarray):
        if isinstance(nparray, list):
            try:
                nparray = np.array(nparray)
            except:
                raise ValueError("Data type not supported for colSpec. It should be an `np.ndarray` object.")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Data type not supported for colSpec. It should be an `np.ndarray` object.")

    # If no column specification requested, just return the orginal array with batchStart and batchEnd rows.
    if rangeStr is None:
        return nparray[batchStart:batchEnd]
    
    else:
        colCount = len(nparray[0])

        # Validate the index range range.
        if (not IndexRange.validate(colCount, rangeStr)):
            raise ValueError("Index range string is not valid.")

        # Different scenarios on the column selections:
        if ":" in rangeStr:
            # Split the ":" to find the range start and end.
            rangeInfo = [string.strip() for string in rangeStr.split(":")]

            # None should be specified for 2-valued tuples.
            if any([(ele == "None" or ele == "") for ele in rangeInfo]):
                # Determine the scenarios for which None is used.
                if rangeInfo[0] != "None" and len(rangeInfo[0]):
                    return nparray[batchStart:batchEnd,int(rangeInfo[0]):]
                elif rangeInfo[1] != "None" and len(rangeInfo[1]):
                    return nparray[batchStart:batchEnd,:int(rangeInfo[1])]
                else:
                    return nparray[batchStart:batchEnd]
            else:
                raise nparray[batchStart:batchEnd,int(rangeInfo[0]):int(rangeInfo[1])]
        
        # Otherwise, it is specifying indexes explicitly. 
        else:
            idxs = IndexRange.parse(colCount, rangeStr)
            return nparray[batchStart:batchEnd,idxs]
```

I don't what's wrong about that, I even don't use exceptions code.
If you ever have this problem's solution, Please help me for the case.

Comment: Look closely at your code, specifically line 2890 in `NeuralSimplycode.py`. What are you trying to do in this line? (hint: it looks like a typo to me ;))

Comment: You can only `raise` an exception, not a numpy array. Did you mean `return`?